# Derive electrical power from electrical work

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, electricity, work

I am a little confused with some aspects of electrical power and electrical work. The example is connected to a thermodynamic problem:

> Consider an adiabatic vessel filled with an arbitrary fluid. Inside the fluid, there is a electric heating coil connected to a power supply at the outside of the vessel. Heat conduction and convection limitations should be neglected.

From the first law of thermodynamics:

$dU = dQ + dW_{el}$ and $dQ = 0$, since the vessel is adiabatic.

Now I am looking for $\frac{dU}{dt}$ and the following equation should be valid: $\frac{dU}{dt}=\frac{dW_{el}}{dt}$.

Since, $W_{el} = E(t)\cdot C(t)$, where $E$ is the voltage and $C$ the charge ($E$ and $C$ to not conflict the thermodynamic nomenclature). Therefore, I thought $\frac{W_{el}}{dt} = \frac{dE(t)}{dt}\cdot C(t) + \frac{dC(t)}{dt}\cdot E(t)$ with $\frac{dC(t)}{dt} = I(t)$.

Unfortunately, I found the following $\frac{dU}{dt}=E(t)\cdot I(t)$, which differ in the term $\frac{E(t)}{dt}\cdot C(t)$. I don't understand where my mistake is, can somebody please clarify?

Comment: Is there any reason to have $\frac{dE}{dt}\neq0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electric power is not a function of how much electric charge flows past a given point in your heater ... it's a function of the rate of charge flow past a given point in your heater.  Electric power is normally given by three equations, depending on what measured variables are given:

1) $P=IV$

2) $P=I^2R$

3) $P=V^2/R$

where $P$ = electrical power, $I$ = current flow in amps, $V$ = voltage drop across a given circuit element, and $R$ = resistance of the circuit element in ohms.

AC current does vary in time, as your post implies, and an integration of the associated sine wave indicates that there is an average value of current, the root mean square value, that is used in equations 1 and 2 above to calculate an average power value over very many cycles of AC power (e.g., several seconds for 60 Hz power).  Unless you are working a problem where you need to know power consumption over one or a few cycles of AC power, the root mean square value is what you want to use.